# Javascript Date instance returning wrong date

Tags: nativescript

I'm doing `new Date()` in Javascript for NS development.

When I run the app on the Android emulator - it returns the GMT time - not the local time.

When I run the same app on an Android device or an iPhone or iPhone emulator - the local time is returned.

I went into the phone settings and made sure the date and TZ were set to automatic. Other apps on the emulator and the date/time widgets display correct local time.

So just wondering why `new Date()` returns GMT time in my NS app - on the emulator.

`console.log( "now=" + new Date() );`

Comment: iOS emulators use the same date / time zone as the system. But Android emulators use its own in their settings. I use the Nexus 5x Emulator with Google Play services, where it recognises my time zone and returns the date as expected. Just make sure which ever emulator you are using has the right time zone in the Date & Time settings.

Comment: You mean the Android phone settings for Date & Time right? Or some emulator specific date/time

Comment: I meant the Date & Time settings on the same emulator where you are facing the issue.

Comment: If you mean the emulator's Android Settings >> Date & Time- that's set to my local TZ and time is correct. If you meant an emulator specific setting - haven't found any such setting on the emulator.